# How to Uninstall Shibbolet 2.5 from Windows 10 and Windows Server 2012

Tags: windows, iis, shibboleth

I'm attempting to uninstall shibboleth-sp-2.5.6.0-win64.msi from my Windows 10 PC.(I have the same problem on Windows Server 2012). It gets stuck with the following message:

> Please wait while the Setup Wizard removes Shibboleth Service Provider.

Eventually, I have to use task manager to kill the process. I have tried rebooting the machine and attempted to uninstall it again but it never works.

Does anyone have any hints?

Also, being unable to uninstall means it prevents re-install.

Answer (score 0):

Is the Java JRE in your environment variables?- Shibboleth is a Java application and will likely rely on the JVM and Java run time environment to be installed and the JAVA_HOME environment variable set up, you should have something like:

```
JAVA_HOME=C\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7
```

and you can test from command line by running java -version

Comment: Per your advice I installed Java and then ran shibboleth-sp-2.5.6.0-win64.msi and choose the "remove" option. It hangs in the same spot as before.

Comment: sorry I gave you some bad advice there, I was thinking of the Shibboleth IDP - It could be open files - are the shibboleth-sp files still being server by your web server?